# I am trying to run jest from root of project to test two files, jest is installed as dev dependency but running test script throws syntaxError?

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs

**`package.json`**

```json
{
  "name": "proj4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "node src/server/index.js",
    "build-dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --open",
    "build-prod": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^4.35.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.1.1",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

```
npm run test       

> proj4@1.0.0 test /Users/tommydates/Desktop/NanoDegree/proj4
> jest

/Users/tommydates/Desktop/NanoDegree/proj4/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:227
    } catch {
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tommydates/Desktop/NanoDegree/proj4/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js:16:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! proj4@1.0.0 test: `jest`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the proj4@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

    npm ERR!     /Users/tommydates/.npm/_logs/2020-10-22T04_03_33_681Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Where is your babel configuration located ?

Comment: .babelrc file at root level i.e proj4/.babelrc

Comment: I have solved it, i basically downgraded my jest two versions and tests started to run jest@24.0.0, i have never had that error before, i also added babel jest as well, cheers for the help